# How to count frequency of unique pair combinations from a column of comma-separated values?

Tags: r, count, combinations, frequency

I have a dataframe with a column ("combo") of comma-separated values indicating event-types that co-occur within the same timeperiod. I am looking for a way to count the frequency of pair-wise combinations (order does not matter; i.e., AB and BA are equivalent).

toy dataframe

```
+------------------------+
|combo      startts endts|
| A,B       02:20  02:23 |
| A,B,D     02:23  02:25 |
| A,C       02:27  02:28 |
+------------------------+
```

Ideal output:

```
+---------------------------+
|combo      | count         |
+---------------------------+
|  AB       | 2             |
|  AC       | 1             |
|  AD       | 1             |
|  BC       | 0             |
|  BD       | 1             |
|  CD       | 0             |
+-----------+---------------+
```

I was thinking of first generating all unique pair-wise combinations, putting that in a column, and then doing a conditional mutate with a regex pattern match; however, I wasn't sure how to refer to the column name abstractly rather than a particular string pattern (or if that is even possible).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this

Input:

```
df <- read.table(text = "combo      startts endts
A,B       02:20  02:23
A,B,D     02:23  02:25
A,C       02:27  02:28", header = TRUE)
```

Solution:

```
# user defined functions
pastecollapse <- function(...) paste(..., collapse = "")
sortedcomb2collapse <- function(x) combn(sort(x), m = 2, FUN = pastecollapse)

# get combos
combos <- strsplit(df$combo, split = ",")

# all possible combos
allcombos <- sortedcomb2collapse(unique(unlist(combos)))

# existing combos
mycombos  <- unlist(lapply(combos, sortedcomb2collapse))

# count combos (show missing combos)
as.data.frame(table(combo = factor(mycombos, levels = allcombos)), responseName = "count")

#>   combo count
#> 1    AB     2
#> 2    AC     1
#> 3    AD     1
#> 4    BC     0
#> 5    BD     1
#> 6    CD     0
```

---

Similarly, with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_sep <- df %>% separate_rows(combo)
allcombos <- df_sep %>% pull(combo) %>% unique %>% sortedcomb2collapse

df_sep %>% 
 group_by(startts, endts) %>% 
 summarise(combo = sortedcomb2collapse(combo), .groups = "drop") %>% 
 mutate(combo = factor(combo, levels = allcombos)) %>% 
 count(combo, name = "count", .drop = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   combo count
#>   <fct> <int>
#> 1 AB        2
#> 2 AC        1
#> 3 AD        1
#> 4 BC        0
#> 5 BD        1
#> 6 CD        0
```

---

Note: in your expected output one possible combination was missing (`CD`). Was it a mistake?

Comment: Thanks for showing me comb and table: I have some reading to do!

With your first solution, I got the following:
**`Error in strsplit(df$combo, split = ",") : non-character argument`**

This was fixed by wrapping (df$combo) in as.character()

With your second solution, I got the following error related to the summarise line:
**``Column `combo` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3``**

And yes, CD should have been there. That was a mistake; it is a valid combination. I've added it in the ideal output now for future readers.

Comment: the first error is probably due to the fact that in your data `combo` is a factor. I had no idea. You handle it in the right way. Force the same transformation for the second solution too. If you still have an error, please add the output of `dput(head(data))` to your question, so that I can find a solution.

Comment: Probably you have an error in the second solution because your `dplyr` version is too old. It must be at least `1.0.0` to work. If you can, try: `update.packages()`

Comment: thanks! updating worked; more reading to do. I did get an odd message; but the function worked.
`Warning message:... is not empty. We detected these problematic arguments:needs_dots These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty. Did you misspecify an argument?`

Comment: I updated dplyr and tidyr packages. I'll try updating all of them

Comment: it should be related to `vctrs` or `tibble`